# Convert Android Java formatted string to Swift

Tags: java, swift, string

```
private String result = String.format("$1#%1$s","myString")
```

How do I get an equivalent result in Swift 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `String(format:_:)` and use `%@` as a reference instead of `%1$s`.

```
let myString = "test"
let result = String(format: "$1#%@", myString) //$1#test
```

Read more about **String Format Specifiers** [in the Cocoa documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: Cocoa string format allows positional format specifiers. Using `%1$@` would have been fine too. Though with only a single value, it's not necessary. This answer should state that the only required change is to use `@` instead of `s`. But even that isn't 100% true. `s` is for C-strings while `@` is for objects. `%s` will work in Cocoa formatters with Swift and Objective-C, you just need to convert the `String` (or `NSString`) into a C-string using the appropriate method on the string.